# Reaching out to customers who don't want your product

Tags: user-research

This may seem like an obvious question, but how can you reach out to customers who don't want to use your product so you can speak with them and learn more about why.

They may have been on the site but haven't completed a purchase or sign up. I'm trying to understand the reasons for people not being interested, their fears and concerns.

Answer (score 2):

**1. By asking them**

There are multiple options for this, you can either use a feedback tool (often UX Tracking tools come with such a feature) or you can implement a "What is the reason you are leaving" question when people are aborting checkout for example.

Either way the majority of people will not answer you.

**2. By watching what they do**

If you are using a tracking tool like Hotjar, Luckyorange etc. you are able to see at what point a lot of users stop using your site and stuff like this, you have to look for patterns, for example people come to a product site and get confused because the information is to cluttered, they will move their mouse, scroll up and down and basically tell you that you need to try a different version of this site, which you can test and validate by comparing the dropout ratios etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a form or a popup or any other way to ask the user why he is leaving, there are a lot of chances they won't answer because they find it annoying.

First make sure your website is well structured and has an intuitive flow + an appealing design. You have good quality images for products and they have all the right info.

After that I would actually implement a live chat window that (thanks 
@TripeHound) offers to connect the user to staff after they have been navigating your website for more than 20-30 seconds, asking them if they need help or additional info.

> Like a small window in the bottom-right corner of the screen sliding
>   up asking if you need help. I usually use cookies to do this only
>   once, so they know someone's there to help them and where to find it.

Comment: A (moderately) prominent "_Click if you want to chat_" button/CTA is fine, but personally, I find a "_Hey, you've not done anything for 30 seconds... let's chat!_" pop-up massively annoying (I might actually be _reading_ what's on the page, or just pausing to drink coffee).

Comment: @TripeHound I don't believe a small window in the bottom-right corner of the screen sliding up asking if you need help only once is that annoying. I usually use cookies to do this only once, so they know someone's there to help them and where to find it. But I guess it's kinda opinion based and depends on what others have experienced.

Comment: A low-key slide-up like that may be OK; my response was probably more triggered by "_**automatically connects** the user to staff_" (as opposed to "_**offers to connect** users..._") which made it sound like a more intrusive thing than you probably meant.

Comment: @TripeHound It did, didn't it? :) Thanks for pointing that out to me. I have updated my answer to make it clearer.